# Using structs in a header files c++

Tags: c++, struct, header-files, implementation

I am having trouble printing what I have in my header file. When I put all my code in just a cpp file everything works, but when I try to use a header file it does not run.

this is my header file, vet.h

```
#ifndef Vet
#define Vet

class LIST
{
private:
    struct PET
    {
        string last_name;
        string pet;
        string animal;
        string color;
        int dob;
};
//enter data
public:
void Read
{
    cout<<"Your pets first name: ";
    cin>>PET.pet;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Your last name: ";
    cin>>PET.last_name;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"What kind of animal do you have: ";
    cin>>PET.animal;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Your animals dob: ";
    cin>>PET.dob;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Your animals color: ";
    cin>>PET.color;
    cin.ignore();
}
};
#endif
```

and this is my cpp file, Veterinary.cpp

```
//read from header file
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Vet.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
LIST P;

P.Read();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void Read` -> `void Read()`

Comment: And `#include <iostream>...` + `std::` in the header..

Comment: `PET` is the name of a type, not of a variable. You need an actual instance of `PET` struct before you can set its fields.

Comment: And `Vet` is a terrible name for a include guard macro.

Comment: Yet another compiler that doesn't seem to generate error messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class has no data member of type PET so member function Read is invalid. You need to define a data member of type PET where you will enter data about your pets.
C++ has no anonymous structures.

Also take into account that directive using namespace std has to be placed before this header with the class definition. Also it would be better if you would include headers `<iostream>` and `<string>`in your header and use qualified standard names instead of using the directive.

The header could look like

```
#ifndef Vet
#define Vet

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class LIST
{
private:
    struct PET
    {
        std::string last_name;
        std::string pet;
        std::string animal;
        std::string color;
        int dob;
   } pet_data;

//enter data
public:
    void Read()
    {
        std::cout<<"Your pets first name: ";
        std::cin>>pet_data.pet;
        std::cout<<"Your last name: ";
        std::cin>>pet_data.last_name;
        std::cout<<"What kind of animal do you have: ";
        std::cin>>pet_data.animal;
        std::cout<<"Your animals dob: ";
        std::cin>>pet_data.dob;
        std::cout<<"Your animals color: ";
        std::cin>>pet_data.color;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: *"C++ has no anonymous structures.*" Unless you consider temporaries. :)

Comment: @cdhowie  temporaries are not anonymous structures. They are unnamed structure. It is different notions.

Comment: for the cpp file, would I still include using namespace std;?

Comment: @user3326689 You have to remove header stdio.h and include header cstdlib where function system is defined. And there is no any need to include the derictive if inside your header you will be use the qualified names.

Comment: okay, I replaced stdio.h with cstdlib and I'm still having problems

Comment: @user3326689  What problems do you have?

Comment: it's showing that I have a lot of syntax errors even though I copied the code you provided me with

Comment: @user33 There was a typo. After function identifier Read there have to be parentheses. See my updated post.

Comment: Now it is running, the parentheses fixed the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Anonymous means "having no name."  Anonymous and unnamed are synonyms.

Comment: @cdhowie You are wrong. C/C++ Standards distinguish anonymous structures and unions and unnamed structures and unions. They have different meanings. For example C++ has only anonymous unions and has no anonymous structures.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Poorly chosen words since in English they have the same meaning.  Anyway my original comment was intended to be a joke.  I'm not really going to continue arguing about something that was intended to be humorous.

Comment: @user3326689 Mark the question as answered.